# The Intergral of $\sin^4x$ without using reduction formula

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

So I've been trying to compute $$\int\sin^4(x)\mathrm{d}x$$ and everywhere they use the reduction formula which we haven't learned yet so I've been wondering if theres another way to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you familiar with integration by parts?

Comment: Unless the curriculum is very, very different in other parts of the world, the "reduction formula" is a basic trigonometric identity which you should have learned in a precalculus class long before ever enrolling in calculus.

Comment: @Sebastiano Why?  What possible purpose could that serve?

Comment: Currently, it is not clear what "the reduction formula" in your question refers to. Please edit your question to be more precise about what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performing integration by parts,

$\begin{align} \int_0^x\sin^2 t\,dt&=\Big[-\cos t\sin t\Big]_0^x+\int_0^x\cos^2 t\,dt\\
&=-\cos x\sin x+\int_0^x(1-\sin^2 t)\,dt\\
&=-\cos x\sin x+\int_0^x 1\,dt-\int_0^x \sin^2 t\,dt\\
&=-\cos x\sin x+x-\int_0^x \sin^2 t\,dt\\
\end{align}$

Therefore,

$\displaystyle \int_0^x \sin^2 t\,dt=-\frac{1}{2}\cos x\sin x+\frac{1}{2}x$

$\begin{align} \int_0^x\sin^4 t\,dt&=\int_0^x(1-\cos^2)\sin^2 t\,dt
\\
&=\int_0^x\sin^2 t\,dt-\int_0^x \cos^2 t\sin^2 t\,dt\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\cos x\sin x+\frac{1}{2}x-\int_0^x \cos^2 t\sin^2 t\,dt\\
\end{align}$

Since, for $t$ real,

$\sin(2t)=2\sin t\cos t$

then,

$\begin{align}
\int_0^x\sin^4 t\,dt&=-\frac{1}{2}\cos x\sin x+\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}{4}\int_0^x \sin^2(2t)\,dt\\
\end{align}$

In the latter integral perform the change of variable $y=2t$,

$\begin{align}
\int_0^x\sin^4 t\,dt&=-\frac{1}{2}\cos x\sin x+\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}{8}\int_0^{2x} \sin^2(y)\,dy\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\cos x\sin x+\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}{8}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\cos (2x)\sin(2x)+\frac{1}{2}\times 2x\right)\\
&=-\frac{1}{4}\sin(2x)+\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{32}\sin(4x)-\frac{1}{8}x\\
&=-\frac{1}{4}\sin(2x)+\frac{3}{8}x+\frac{1}{32}\sin(4x)\\
\end{align}$

Therefore,

$\displaystyle \boxed{\int \sin^4 x\,dx=\frac{3}{8}x+\frac{1}{32}\sin(4x)-\frac{1}{4}\sin(2x)+C}$

($C$ a real constant)

Comment: This appears to be the only answer that actually does what the questioner asks and performs the computation without using a power reduction formula or using other advanced techniques (such as complex integration) which are likely unfamiliar to the OP.  Congratulations.

Comment: Thank you kindly <3

Answer (score 2):

Use this $$\sin^2x = \frac{1-\cos (2x)}2 \implies \sin^4x = \left( \frac{1-\cos 2x}2 \right)^2=\frac{1+\cos^2 (2x) -2 \cos 2x}{4}$$

And then,

$$\cos^2 (2x)=\frac{1+\cos (4x) }{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way might be to use the fact that
$$\sin(x)=\frac{1}{2}i \left(e^{-ix}-e^{ix}\right)$$
$$\sin^4(x)=\frac{1}{16} \left(e^{-ix}-e^{ix}\right)^4$$
And you just need to expand and integrate it.

Comment: In my opinion, this is not just an alternative way, but the **definitive** way to do it, since it immediately explains all the coefficients of the terms.